# To use stye/ js files without using base_url() In codegnitor

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

For linking my files in head  I am using base_url () to bind the files .like

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/admin/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But for security reason I have not use this approach Please help me if you know the best way to links files /images in Codeigniter.

Comment: ***But for security reason*** can you explain what can be happened ??

Comment: Why are you want to use absolute urls for assets?

Comment: because my structure to render view is nested eg  adim>register>register.php

Comment: #Abdulla Nilam  reason is that  when I am using  base url its giving me

server url eg . https://172.19.102.110